# How to programmatically get the XML code of a view in Android?

Tags: android, xml

Sorry, this is a very small post but I'm curious about a specific idea:  I'm trying to figure out how I can get the XML code of a button, text view, etc.  Basically, the idea is that I click a specific view and its XML code appears in a large text view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that.  The UI doesn't run on XML, the initial xml is used to create the view hierarchy (possibly, you don't have to use xml at all) then discarded.  The views do not store their state as xml, that would be incredibly inefficient.

Comment: What does the UI run on?

Comment: Actual writes to RAM locations that are memory mapped to the screen's pixels.  The screen then reads those pixels at a fixed rate.  Android has a slight abstraction over this (the Canvas abstraction).  But its several steps removed and closer to the hardware than the markup language as used by browsers.